# How do I find the index of maximum and minimum values in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I need to write a code to display the location of the highest and lowest tx value. Nothing appears to be working. Here is my code:

```
%times
tx=[tf-to];
tx=[130 103 152 163 218 278 82 195 221 154 94 159 214 185];


s=(130+103+52+163+218+278+82+195+221+154+94+159+214+185);
%minimum and maximum times

minvalue=min(tx);
maxvalue=max(tx);
```

How do I edit this code to show the max and min values of tx only??

Comment: Read the documentation! The answer is explicitly there. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html

Comment: Did you even googled this?

Comment: try typing `help max` or `doc max` in matlab before asking questions like this...

Answer (score 2):

```
[minvalue,idx_min]=min(tx);
[maxvalue,idx_max]=max(tx);
```

This uses the second output of both `min` and `max`, which returns the index of the min/max value respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Adding two inline functions to return the min and max is a possibility.

```
    min_index = @(vector) find(vector==min(vector))
    max_index = @(vector) find(vector==max(vector))

    idx_min = min_index(tx);
    idx_max = max_index(tx);
```